# Do es6 modules negate the need for browserify/webpack?

Tags: ecmascript-6, browserify, webpack

ES6 modules allow us to create modules of code that can be exported and imported as dependencies.

Browserify and Webpack do the same thing. So am I right in assuming that if I use ES6 along with something like babel to transpile my code then webpack and browserify are not needed?

Comment: ES6 modules define a syntax. Browserify/Webpack bundle modules to make them work in browsers (especially old ones). They *work together*, and cannot replace each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you use it in the browser, you currently still need webpack or browserify.**

Let's have a look at an example:

The following

```
import * as name from 'name.js';
```

is turned into:

```
'use strict';

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__esModule) { return obj; } else { var newObj = {}; if (obj != null) { for (var key in obj) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) newObj[key] = obj[key]; } } newObj['default'] = obj; return newObj; } }

var _nameJs = require('name.js'); // Here, a function named "require" is still needed

var name = _interopRequireWildcard(_nameJs);
```

[Check it out in the Babel Repl](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=import%20*%20as%20name%20from%20%27name.js%27%3B)

As you see, babel relies on the [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) Method `require` (really any implementation of it) to do the import. As node.js implements CommonJS, it would work, but no browser currently implements it. AFAIK there aren't [any browsers that support *ES 6 Modules* natively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#compat-desktop) either.

Comment: That answer is outdated.

Answer (score 3):

As elaborated [here](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) - ES6 modules have two aspects:

> The ES6 module standard has two parts:
>
> - Declarative syntax (for importing and exporting)
> - Programmatic loader
>     API: to configure how modules are loaded and to conditionally load
>     modules

Babel handles only the first aspect - ie. declarative syntax for importing and exporting and does not provide its own loader.

What people using ES6 modules today do, is usually one of the following:

- Use Babel to transpile ES6 modules syntax to an existing module implementation like CommonJS/AMD and appropriately an available tool like Webpack/browserify/requirejs can be used to then load/bundle the js assets.
- Alternatively there are loaders like [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) which provide support for Programmatic loader API (through [ES6 module loader polyfill](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader). Using this tool does allow you get rid of Browserify/Webpack but, as of now, you are just swapping one tool for another. It is likely that as more and more libraries like [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io) embrace ES6 modules, and recommend the standardized `System.import` syntax -  SystemJS will soar in popularity.

Another aspect is compatibility with existing ecosystem of modules (especially on npm). It is noteworthy that you are not losing compatibility with existing ecosystem with either of the strategies: Both webpack and SystemJS allow loading and bundling of commonjs as well as AMD modules.

As far as bundling of assets is concerned, persistent connection support in HTTP 2 has already signficantly reduced the value of concatenation of javascript files. Though dead-code elimination after uglification of a full javascript bundle still remains a valuable optimization.

As authors of tools like [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) have repeatedly pointed out, statically analysable nature of ES6 modules makes tree-shaking and dead code elimination much more effective.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I'd say there are three points to this. Please correct me if I'm wrong...

1. If you want the best performance for the user, then es6modules are better. There are scenarios were they do perform better (less http-requests, better caching) and there's AFAIK no scenario were they perform worse.
2. `browserify` is much better integrated with the at the moment most used package manager — `npm`.

With es6modules you do have to specify a relative path to modules within `node_modules` instead of just the name of the module like with `browserify`. You could write a preprocessor to solve this problem of es6modules and execute it within a build-process (it would just change the path if it is not a relative path). But that is of course additional work and browserify provides that feature out of the box.

Furthermore most modules within the npm registry probably use commonjs syntax and not es6modules syntax. That means if you want to use a module directly from npm you'd have to fork it in order to leverage the benefits of es6modules.

Note: AFAIK transforming of es6modules syntax into something else (like with babel) does not keep the benefits of the es6modules syntax.

3. Probably you will also have some kind of build-process when you use es6modules (like mentioned at the second point or if you want to also minify or do something else). With `browserify` there are pretty good tools available which make development pretty convenient so that you can work in an effective way, like for example `watchify` which does increase the time required for the build significantly due to caching.